# How to find $\mathbb{E}(V)$ where $V = \frac{100}{2^X}$ and $X\sim \Gamma(3,1)$.

Tags: conditional-expectation

How would I compute this? I tried doing: 
$$
\mathbb{E}(V) = \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(V|X)) = \mathbb{E} (\mathbb{E}(\frac{100}{2^X}|X=x))  
$$
but that seems to not help at all... since doesn't the inner expectation just become $100/2^X$?

Comment: Have you tried computing the corresponding integral?

Comment: **Hint:** If $f$ is the PDF of $X$, then $$ \mathbb E [g(X)] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)f(x) \,\mathrm d x. $$

Comment: I tried but wasn't sure if it's correct.  
Since why couldn't I just do $\mathbb{E}(V) = \mathbb{E}(\frac{100}{2^X} )$ instead of usnig the law of iterated expectation?

Comment: From what I understand, $E(\frac{100}{2^X} | X=x) = \frac{100}{2^X}$ since it's like keeping $X$ constant